# Cross-platform background silent process execution in python

Tags: python, process, background

Within a python program I need to run a command in background, without displaying its output. Therefore I'm doing `os.system("nohup " + command + " &")` for now.

Edit : `command` shouldn't be killed/closed when python program exits.

However that will only work on Linux, and the content of the file will end up in `nohup.out` but I don't need it there. Therefore I'm looking for a platform independent solution.
`os.spawnlp(os.P_DETACH, command)` doesn't work, even with the `*p` version so as to be able not to enter full path to application.

NB. I know that `command` is generally platform dependent, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a daemon in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a daemon process. Look at [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) or http://blog.ianbicking.org/daemon-best-practices.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972362/spawning-process-from-python/972383#972383 looks good

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
process = Popen(['command', 'arg'], stdout=PIPE)
```

Comment: Works fine. But `command` is killed when python program closes.

Comment: You'll have to wait for it to finish. You can use `process.communicate()` or poll on the return code.

Comment: `command` has to be independent from python script. If I kill python, `command` has to keep running.