# Gunicorn :: reload from the application itself

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have recently created a version control page from my application to manage the deployment process.

(Yeah, I know, github + hooks are better than rewriting from zero. But we are in Iran and our beloved government has blocked all the ssh connections to outside of the country. :(( )

There is a merge + reload action in the page. the merge is working like the other parts, but the reload part fails without any message. I have added sudo row for kill command and the user of the worker process has enough permission. I even executed the code form django shell and it reloaded the process.

**Is there any restriction for receiving signals, such as workers not being able to reload their master?**

Here's the related codes:

```
def command(x):
    return str(Popen(x.split(' '), stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0])

pid = open(PATH + "/logs/gunicorn.pid").readline().strip()
cmd = "sudo kill -HUP %s" % pid
content += command(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess off the top of my head is that the restart is not working because the process calling the reload is being killed.  Maybe try to daemonize a subprocess that exits after calling the reload?  Take a look at this post:

[spawning process from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972362/spawning-process-from-python)