# Causes of sqlite3.OperationalError "locking protocol" exception?

Tags: python, sqlite

After enabling [Write-Ahead Log](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) mode for a volatile SQLite3 database (`PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL`), my concurrency tests began raising this error. I discovered that this happens when the Python process is forked and a connection is left open to a database in WAL mode. Any subsequent `execute()` on that database, even with a new connection, throws this `'locking protocol'` exception.

Disabling WAL mode (`PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE`) makes the problem disappear, and neither does any `'database is locked'` error occur either. The `'locking protocol'` exception seems reflect the [SQLITE_PROTOCOL](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#protocol) code underneath which is documented as:

> The SQLITE_PROTOCOL result code indicates a problem with the file locking protocol used by SQLite.

I'm using Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.12.6 Sierra. I think the problem is in Python's `sqlite3` module and how it deals with being forked, rather than an issue in SQLite3 itself. I know now how to work around the issue but as per the main question, **what is the root cause of this issue?**

P.S. - I'm not using any threads and am forking by [spawning a daemon child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972362/spawning-process-from-python).

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6).

Answer (score 3):

SQLite3 is obviously not thread-safe as [per the FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6) but, as [CL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl) pointed out in the comments to my question, there *is* a line relating to forking there:

> Under Unix, you should not carry an open SQLite database across a fork() system call into the child process.

This doesn't exactly provide an answer as to the *cause*, however it does point out a solution: close *ALL* SQLite connections in (or before) a `fork()` process! Holding onto forked connections prevents new connections from taking place across any process!